# Swift: OSLog `No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'` for enum?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following test code:

```
import OSLog

enum MyEnum {
    case testing
}

extension Logger {
    
    static let testLog = Logger(subsystem: "my sub", category: "testCat")
    
}

func testLog() {
    let me = MyEnum.testing
    
    let someDate = Date()
    
//    Logger.testLog.info("testing log 1 \(me)") // << No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'
    Logger.testLog.info("testing log 1 \(someDate)") // << WORKS
    
}
```

When I run the `testLog()` function with `Logger.testLog.info("testing log 1 \(me)")` I get the following error:

`No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'`

How can I log the `me` enum?

Comment: It appears to be due to `MyEnum` not conforming to `CustomStringConvertible`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because the string interpolation on swift is not compatible with log.

`@HangarRash` As you said, using CustomStringConvertible will solve it.

```
enum MyEnum: String, CustomStringConvertible {
    case testing = "testing"
    
    var description: String {
         return self.rawValue
     }
}
```

```
    func testLog() {
        let me = MyEnum.testing
        
        let someDate = Date()
        
        Logger.testLog.info("testing log 1 \(me)") // << No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'
        Logger.testLog.info("testing log 1 \(someDate)") // << WORKS
        
    }
```